# Is there any hardware which converts out of range floating-point to non-{zero/min/max} integer?

Tags: performance

Usually hardware converts out of range floating-point to zero/min/max integer.

Is there any hardware which converts out of range floating-point to non-{zero/min/max} integer?

Comment: What kind of hardware for what type of measurement?

Comment: Any hardware for which a [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))+ implementation exists. No particular type of measurement. General computations using integer and floating-point arithmetic (including conversions from one to the other and vice versa).